# Is JSONKit creating memory leaks?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, xcode4.5, jsonkit

I have been using [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) in my app, but now that I have upgraded to Xcode 4.5.1 and run the analyze, Xcode is reporting possible memory leaks in JSONKit code.

`/Users/aleksa.topic/SVN/Apple/iTTChart/trunk/iTTChart/Other Sources/JSONKit.m:682:23: Memory is never released; potential leak of memory pointed to by 'array'`
(and the it gives the same potential leak for dictionary).

Does anyone have some experience with this? Is it really creating memory leaks or is it just that Xcode is't analyzing good enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a false positive in the static analyzer. There's a [bug report](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/issues/98) trying to resolve it.

Comment: And is there a way to make analyzer ignore that?

Answer (score 2):

See this [link](https://github.com/shazron/JSONKit/commit/5c330695e8b689e6ffb5b79db23cb630b0e921f8). Just replace the lines marked as - with the one marked as +.

```
-    if((array = [array init]) == NULL) { return(NULL); }
+    if([array init] == NULL) { free(array); return(NULL); }
```

---

```
-    if(JK_EXPECT_F((array->objects = (id *)malloc(sizeof(id) * array->capacity)) == NULL)) { [array autorelease]; return(NULL); }
+    if(JK_EXPECT_F((array->objects = (id *)malloc(sizeof(id) * array->capacity)) == NULL)) { free(array); return(NULL); }
```

---

```
-    if((dictionary = [dictionary init]) == NULL) { return(NULL); }
+    if([dictionary init] == NULL) { free(dictionary);return(NULL); }
```

---

```
-    if(JK_EXPECT_F((dictionary->entry = (JKHashTableEntry *)calloc(1UL, sizeof(JKHashTableEntry) * dictionary->capacity)) == NULL)) { [dictionary autorelease]; return(NULL); }
+    if(JK_EXPECT_F((dictionary->entry = (JKHashTableEntry *)calloc(1UL, sizeof(JKHashTableEntry) * dictionary->capacity)) == NULL)) { free(dictionary); return(NULL); }
```

Comment: I'm not sure of this being a false positive, since I've had this memory leak occur. This fix doesn't leak

Answer (score 1):

Replace `((array = [array init]) == NULL)` by `(dictionary == NULL)` and use `free(array)` function instead of `[array autorelease]` to fix it. 
Because it's allecated manually so it shoult be released manualy too.